# Two Circuits down and no Breakers Tripped

Tags: electrical

I had one 110V circuit running four CPU (13v) devices (Laptop, Switching hub etc) and a completely separate 220v circuit running two CPU Servers (13v output 1,300W draw each).  This set up had been running for two months as is no problems.  Yesterday I added a third server to the 220v circuit and it ran flawlessly for an hour or so.  Then ALL of it went down..... both the 110v and the 220v circuits.  I checked and neither breaker had gone (I reset them anyway).  I flipped the main breaker and no difference.  I grabbed my wire tester and it lit up on both lines all the way to the devices yet NONE of the devices are working.  No smoke, no bad smells no fire no nothing.  Is there such an issue as a ground wire needing to be upgraded or some such thing that would allow pos juice to flow to an outlet yet not allow a device to power up?  I'm not an electrician clearly if it needs to be said lol.  Thanx very much for any input you may have.

Comment: Have you plugged a lamp into any of those outlets? Need to determine whether the issue is with the equipment vs the circuit. A wire tester can still show continuity even if the current is really low. A lamp will tell you if you're getting more than just phantom voltage.

Comment: You likely have an open neutral -- be careful you my fry other stuff.  Also, in what country  are you located?

Comment: I'm in Canada.  I have not plugged anything else into the circuits; mostly because I don't have anything else that runs on 220v and I have not tried the lamp idea.  I will give that a go on the 110v circuit and see what happens.  I have the breakers turned off to both at the moment to avoid damage to anything else.

Comment: Do the two circuits share any wires?  (Other than ground, we don't care if they share ground).  Who wired this?   Do you have any other loads in this house? Does the rest of the house work?     @Tyson a lost neutral wouldn't affect 240V equipment, but a lost phase would.

Comment: @Harper sure, unless it's 4-wire equipment that also needs neutral because part of its not really 240v.

Comment: The circuits are totally separate other than they go to the same B panel.  it's in an out build unrelated to my house.  all other lights in the building work.  I wired the 220v and the 110v was done years ago by an electrician.

Comment: @Tyson the equipment is / are 3 x 15a 220v input  Delta Power Supply Units 2,400W Max  13v (output).  The draw on each was 1,300W peak I believe and they are 3 wire devices (one neutral two hot) C19 style plugs.

Comment: Plugged in a lamp to the 110v and the lamp worked (two prong).  I then plugged the laptop into one plug on the box and the power bar into the othe.  The laptop would run by itself and one item from the PB would run by it self but as soon as I added more draw by turning on other device it would go down.  By go down I mean the Laptop would shut down or the hub would cycle on and off etc.  It still would not throw the breaker though.  Again the 110v has nothing to do with the 220v other than they both go to the same panel.

Comment: What do you mean by power bar? Just a power strip, or a UPS?

Comment: It's possible you have a loose connection somewhere. Once you start drawing a certain amount of current, the resistance generates enough heat in the wire to (physically) move it, causing a break in the circuit. When it cools, it moves back and the connection is restored. Backstab connectors on cheap outlets are a common culprit. Use the breaker to disconnect the circuit and inspect your connections inside the outlet boxes, move wires from backstabs to the screw terminals if you encounter their use.

Comment: What do you mean by power bar? Just a power strip, or a UPS? – Hart CO 1 hour ago
a power strip.  Standard run of the mill type stuff with a reset button etc.  I have tried three different bars with the same result.

Answer (score -1):

Are any of the outlets GFCI? Check the button and lights on all of them and push in the reset switch.

Comment: none of the plugs are GFCI